# How does one use Ant to accept optional Command line arguments?

Tags: java, ant

The java program that I am running has 2 mandatory command line arguments and an optional third argument.  Here is my build.xml at the moment:

```
<project name="HashTest" basedir="." default="main">
        <property name="src.dir"        value="src"/>
        <property name="build.dir"      value="build"/>
        <property name="classes.dir"    value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
        <property name="jar.dir"        value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
        <property name="HashTest"       value="com.HashTest.HashTest"/>

        <target name="clean">
                <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
        </target>

        <target name="compile">
                <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
                <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>
        </target>

        <target name="jar" depends="compile">
                <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
                <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/HashTest.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
                        <manifest>
                                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${HashTest}"/>
                        </manifest>
                </jar>
        </target>


        <target name="run" depends="jar">
                <java jar="${jar.dir}/HashTest.jar" fork="true">
                        <arg value="${data}"/>
                        <arg value="${loadfactor}"/>
                        <arg value="${debug}"/>
                </java>
        </target>

        <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>
        <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
</project>
```

This forces the user to enter 3 arguments.  I tried adding another run target with only 2 args defined but ant didn't like it. I know I could create two separately named run targets one with 2 args and another with 3 but I would like to avoid that if possible, for the sake of simplicity.

I'd like the user to simply have to enter:

```
ant -Ddata=<num> -DloadFactor=<num> -Ddebug=<num>
```

or:

```
ant -Ddata=<num> -DloadFactor=<num>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can provide default values for each property, you may define them in the `build.xml` and then override only the ones you want to supply when calling `ant`:

```
<project name="HashTest" basedir="." default="main">

    ...

    <!-- default values for each properties -->
    <property name="data" value="0"/>
    <property name="loadFactor" value="0"/>
    <property name="debug" value="1"/>

    ...

</project>
```

following command line:

```
ant -Ddata=1 -DloadFactor=10 -Ddebug=0
```

will invoke your java program with arguments 1, 10 and 0. Whereas, the following one:

```
ant -DloadFactor=3
```

will invoke it with arguments 0, 3, and 1 (using default values for both `data`and `debug` arguments).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using at least Ant 1.9.1 you can use [`ant:if` or `ant:unless` to have optional arguments](https://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html).

First, add the `if` and `unless` namespaces to your `<project>` element...

```
<project name="tryit"
    xmlns:if="ant:if"
    xmlns:unless="ant:unless"
>
```

...then add `if:set` to the `<arg>` element nested under `<java>`...

```
<arg value="${debug}" if:set="debug"/>
```